# Jquery .click function not working on div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am just trying out .click for first time, but not working with div

https://jsfiddle.net/djsreeraj/rnL7stsm/

html

```
<body>
<div id="score">0</div> 
<div id="start">Start</div>
</body>
```

css code

```
#start {
    width: 50px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font: bold 15px arial;
    background-color: #dedede;
    color: #000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    position: absolute;
  }
  #start:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

this is the jquery code ,the .click function is not working, how to fix it?

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

$("#start").click(function () {
            alert("Hello!");
            $("#start").hide();
        });
  });
```

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/rnL7stsm/2/

Comment: thought online editors come with it as preloaded

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to add jquery to the page.

Edited fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rnL7stsm/1/

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

 $("#start").click(function () {
                alert("Hello!");
                $("#start").hide();
            });
});
```

I also removed the  tag.

Comment: i tried on editors like codepen, jsfiddle , should i include there too?

Comment: yes, you need to include jquery wherever you want to use it.

Comment: Thanks it worked, thought editor comes with it as preloaded